# How to remove a shared datastore from a user with edit priviliges without deleting

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a problem when I share a datastore with another user with edit privileges. I can't see a way of removing the datastore listed on the non-owners datastore list without deleting the owners own datastore.

Am I missing a way to do this?

Comment: Cross-linking with the Dropbox devoloper forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=121737.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the non-owner to no longer see the datastore in their datastore list, you need to delete it (from the non-owner's account). That won't actually delete the datastore... the owner and any others who have opened the datastore will still see it in their lists.

Think of it more as an "unlink" operation.

Comment: I was deleting tables and had a listener that was removing empty datastores instead of just deleting the datastore directly, silly mistake, thank you